# vim function does not detect length change of a line after substitution

Tags: function, vim

Here is a vim function that changes certain lines by replacing single split pipe characters with 2 spaces. It reports that lines are the same length after substitution as before it

```
" :T5 replaces all ¦ with 2 spaces
com! T5 call T5()
function! T5()
    let @l=len(getline("'a"))
    'a,'bs/¦/  /ge
    let @m=len(getline("'a"))
    let @n=@m-@l
    exe "norm 'ak$xp".@n.".'bj$."
endfunction
```

@n is persistently zero.

Here is a data sample that it fails on

```
----------------------------------------------
Special number¦Sign¦Exponent (biased)¦Mantissa
--------------¦----¦-----------------¦--------
      +0      ¦ 0  ¦        0        ¦   0    
      -0      ¦ 1  ¦        0        ¦   0    
      +       ¦ 0  ¦       FFH       ¦   0    
      -       ¦ 1  ¦       FFH       ¦   0    
     NaN      ¦0/1 ¦       FFH       ¦  !=0   
  Denormals   ¦0/1 ¦        0        ¦  !=0   
----------------------------------------------
```

It does the space substitution with spaces, but does not extend the two lines entirely of dashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`len()` returns the number of bytes in the string, not the number of cell used. From `:h len()`:

```
len({expr})     The result is a Number, which is the length of the argument.
                When {expr} is a String or a Number the length in bytes is
                used, as with |strlen()|.
```

The `¦` characters takes 2 bytes, same as two spaces, so the value of `len(getline("'a"))` stays the same.

---

Use `strdisplaywidth()` instead, which returns the number of cells displayed:

```
strdisplaywidth({expr}[, {col}])            strdisplaywidth()

        The result is a Number, which is the number of display cells
        String {expr} occupies on the screen when it starts at {col}.
        When {col} is omitted zero is used.  Otherwise it is the
        screen column where to start.  This matters for Tab
        characters.
        The option settings of the current window are used.  This
        matters for anything that's displayed differently, such as
        'tabstop' and 'display'.
        When {expr} contains characters with East Asian Width Class
        Ambiguous, this function's return value depends on 'ambiwidth'.
        Also see |strlen()|, |strwidth()| and |strchars()|.
```